# Android Bindings Stopped working

Tags: java, android, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

Just suddenly my bindings for android stoped working, anything I build now, I just get this message.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' with value type java.lang.String on android.widget.EditText.
>   file:C:\path\to\layout\layout.xml
>   loc:85:12 - 96:54
>   ****\ data binding error ****

**What I have tried**

**First** it was suggested the bindings won't compile if there are errors in my files, so removed all layout files where I used bindings up to one file  `layout.xml`. There I have

```
 <EditText
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="@{model.name}" />
```

... and it works well, however if i add the two-way binding `android:text="@={model.name}"` It throws the previous error.

**Next**, I add

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static String captureEditTextValue(EditText view) {
    return view.getText().toString();
}
```

...then it throws new error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find event 'android:textAttrChanged' on View type 'android.widget.EditText'
>   file:C:\Users\EdgeTech\AndroidStudioProjects\purse\purse-customer\app\src\main\res\layout\get_phone_layout.xml
>   loc:85:12 - 96:54
>   ****\ data binding error ****

**Went further**, to refactor to this

```
 @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text", event = "android:textAttrChanged")
 public static String captureEditTextValue(EditText view) {
        return view.getText().toString();
 }
```

...still gives previous error.

**My Setup**

- Android Studio: 2.3.3
- Gradle Build Tools: 2.3.3

Comment: When it comes to two-way binding, `android:text="@={model.name}"` this line is enough if your variable is `String`, If you have other datatypes then you need to do inverse binding.

Comment: @RaviRupareliya yes its' a string.

Comment: Then as i already told,if it is `String`, `InverseBinding` is not at all needed.

Comment: @RaviRupareliya, okay but its still doesn't build regardless

Comment: Can you post the rest of the XML and the code in your model? That would help. If you have a short project that demonstrate this problem, that would be ideal.

Comment: Can you post your whole XML file and your whole model file?

Comment: I am having the same issue on Android Preview since Friday. Code that used to work stopped working on a simple `String` bind on an `EditText`. Marked answer does not fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two way binding needs this type:

```
ObservableField<T>
```

for example:
in viewModel.class

```
public ObservableField<String> productName = new ObservableField<>();
```

in layout.xml:

```
<EditText
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="@={viewModel.productName}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `InverseBindingAdapter` as I do not believe it is necessary for a String.

Then, in your EditText XML tag, change `android:text="@={model.name}` --> ``` android:text="@={`` + model.name}" ```.

Comment: Please let me know if this does not fix your issue. I see you are running on Android 2.3+ (the minimum support for the bug fix) so this solution could very well solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to change:

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static String captureEditTextValue(EditText view) {
    return view.getText().toString();
}
```

to:

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static String getText(TextView view) {
    return view.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

However it's working now. It started working back after I upgraded my Build Tools and SDK Platform tools to version **26**. Not still sure why it was breaking with version **25** though.

I tried all the solutions provided, all to no avail, upgrading it, was the only solution that worked for me.